# Is there a way to delay a CORS request?

Tags: jquery, cors, delay

I am using CORS to pull back some content from a webpage. Obviously this webpage is on a different server than the one I'm using (thus the need for CORS). Here's my blippit of code.

```
<div id="target-div2"></div>
<script>$('#target-div2').load('http://dcll.ent.sirsi.net/client/en_US/test/search/results?qu=NEW_DVDS #results_wrapper');</script>
```

Basically this fetches the content within the div with the ID *results_wrapper* and puts it in my *target-div2* on my page. The problem I'm having is that the code fetches the content before the off-server page is 100% loaded. Well sort of...the off-server page loads and then appears to also have to go off-server to fetch some images. So basically the page initially loads with some temporary placeholder images and then a script runs and it goes to fetch the missing images. Does that make sense?

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to delay the gathering of the content for a second before returning it back to my page.

Comment: Sure, just wrap this `load` in a `setTimeout`, which is wrapped in `$(document).ready`. This should delay it just fine.

Comment: Place your code in a DOMReady handler; `$(function() { /* your code here */ });`

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I realize I can delay running the script from my end but what I need is a way for the script to run, it his that off-server page, waits a second, gathers the content, and then returns it. I know I'm kind of fishing in the night here. It seems like that [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method knows to wait for at least a certain amount of time, until the page loads or something...is there a way to make it wait a little longer? @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to set up a callback like this ?

```
<div id="target-div2"></div>
<script>
var callback = function(){
    $('#target-div2').load('http://dcll.ent.sirsi.net/client/en_US/test/search/results?qu=NEW_DVDS #results_wrapper');
}
$( document ).ready(callback);
</script>
```

Comment: `delay` doesn't do anything here.

Comment: Shoot that didn't work. What I'm wondering is if there is a way to load that off-server page, wait until the off-sever page is completely loaded and then return the content. Or if there is a way to load that off-server page...wait a second and then gather and return the content...

Comment: Can you try <div id="target-div2"></div>
<script>
var delay = 1000;//delay in ms
var callback = function(){
    $('#target-div2').load('http://dcll.ent.sirsi.net/client/en_US/test/search/results?qu=NEW_DVDS #results_wrapper');
}
$( document ).ready(function(){setTimeout(callback,delay)});
</script>